# How to disable batching for ACTION_MOVE event recieved in onInterceptTouchEvent?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, motionevent, android-touch-event

Presently, I receive at most two  `ACTION_MOVE` after `ACTION_DOWN`, and no matter how much I drag, no subsequent `ACTION_MOVE` is received in `onInterceptTouchEvent` of `ViewPager`.

Is there a way to receive `ACTION_MOVE` more frequently?

Comment: Which device are you using? Have you tried different devices? Are you logging the `ACTION_MOVE` events?

Comment: @jaibatrik I am using Samasung galaxy s2, running cyanogen. Yes I am logging `ACTION_MOVE` events. They show up in `onDispatchEvent` but not in `onInterceptTouchEvent`, so I don't think it is device issue. I have solved my issue by hooking into `onDispatchEvent`, but it would like to know if we can increase the frequency of `onInterceptTouchEvent`.